# JQuery Mobile persistent footer duplicating on internal pages

Tags: jquery, mobile, footer, persistent

I'm building a virtual museum where users can step through rooms (pages) by using two buttons located in a persistent footer (data-position="fixed", data-fullscreen="true" and same data-id on all pages). I want the footer to stay fixed during transitions which seems to function quite well. However, when i navigate back and forth through the pages, at some point the footer seems to duplicate. It gets obvious when i lower the footer opacity. The weird thing is these duplicates line up after each other OUTSIDE the data-role="page" elements in the DOM.

I found this link 
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-footer-multiplying-on-internal-pages

but didn't find a way to select multiple footers and assign them the class="ui-footer-duplicate"

Maybe i should add that i'm using the same file for all the rooms and i dynamically change contents and the links on the buttons.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is here?

Thanks for your help!